# php ftp_get() not working in Docker container

Tags: php, docker, ftp

I am trying to retrieve a file from an ftp in a Docker container using php. The script I have works locally, but the file is not being retrieved from Docker. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-cli php5-curl git cron ca-certificates
ADD startup.sh /
CMD ["/startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh just downloads the actual script to run from source control, and sets up a cron job. The call to the ftp is this:

```
 $connection = ftp_connect('theftpsite.com');
 $login = ftp_login($connection, 'myusername', 'mypassword');
 ftp_get($connection, 'localfile.xml', 'remotefile.xml', FTP_BINARY);
 ftp_close($connection);
```

The erros we receive are

```
ftp_fget(): Switching to Binary mode.
```

followed by

```
FTP Pull failed
```

Is there anything else I need to install in my container to get this to work?

Comment: "not working" - means what? What does it do? Any error message? Do you even know, if it is the `ftp_get` that fails? How, if you are not doing any error checking?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the errors we got to the question, and how we resolved the problem in the end.

Answer (score 3):

We needed to add

```
ftp_pasv($connection, TRUE);
```

before the ftp_get(). This is the working solution:

```
$connection = ftp_connect('theftpsite.com');
$login = ftp_login($connection, 'myusername', 'mypassword');
ftp_pasv($connection, TRUE); 
ftp_get($connection, 'localfile.xml', 'remotefile.xml', FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($connection);
```